# How to efficiently calculate combinations of the sum of two lists, and avoid selecting combinations containing only elements of the second list?

Tags: python, optimization, combinations

I am not the best coder, but I am trying to figure out how to calculate the number of possible combinations and actually generate every combination, but with some rules.  I have two sets of "things," primaries (P) and secondaries (S).  In this case I have P = 16 and S = 7. So a valid combination needs at least one P value in it, but does not need an S value to be valid, thus:

P1, S1, S2 is Valid

P1, P2, P3 is Valid

P1, P2, P3, P4, S1, S2 is Valid

But,

S1, S2, S3 is NOT Valid.

Also P1, S1 is the same as S1, P1.  I wrote a program, which I think does the trick, but it is terrible and takes like two days to run.

I created this code, which outputs the correct results (I think), but which is very resource intensive:

```
import itertools

P_num = 16
S_num = 7
R = P_num + S_num

P = list(range(1,P_num+1))
S = list(range(1,S_num+1))
P = ["P" + str(suit) for suit in P]
S = ["S" + str(suit) for suit in S]
stuff = P + S

totalarray = {new_list: [] for new_list in range(1,R+1)}

for L in range(len(stuff) + 1):
    print(L)
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        sublist = sorted(subset)
        if any(x in sublist for x in P):
            if sublist not in totalarray[L]:
                totalarray[L].append(sublist)

run = 0
for each in totalarray.keys():
    print(each, len(totalarray[each]))
    run += len(totalarray[each])

print(run)
```

I could really use some advise on ways to optimize this problem, I am sure there is a better way to do this without so many nested operations. I am hoping to get the same results, but just more optimized.

Comment: Are you sure this code isn't taking forever to run because there are a _lot_ of combinations? I would also suggest using a generator for functions like thid that require a long list of items.

Comment: There are (2^16 - 1)*(2^7) = 8388480 combinations of this form. Generating a list of all these combinations will not take much time, but printing them all will take several hours.

Comment: @bb1 Generating the list *their way* takes **a lot** of time.

Comment: @KellyBundy True, but it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing to a terminal is relatively slow.

According to your rules, there will be 8,388,480 valid combinations.

Writing the valid combinations to a file will be much faster than sending output to a terminal.

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from time import perf_counter

OUTPUT_FILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/combos.txt'
def isvalid(c):
    for v in c:
        if v[0] == 'P':
            return True
    return False

start = perf_counter()

P_num = 16
S_num = 7

stuff = [f'P{n}' for n in range(1, P_num+1)] + [f'S{n}' for n in range(1, S_num+1)]
count = 0
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as cfile:
    for k in range(1, len(stuff)+1):
        for combo in combinations(stuff, k):
            if isvalid(combo):
                cfile.write(f'{combo}\n')
                count += 1

print(f'Count={count:,}, Duration={perf_counter()-start:.2f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
Count=8,388,480, Duration=11.07s
```

Comment: It's a good sign to see that we got the same answer!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, your problem can be speeded up drastically using a bit of combinatorics. Here is the code:

```
from math import comb
P_num = 16
S_num = 7
total = P_num + S_num

solution = 0

for length in range(total):
    for P in range(1, P_num+1):
        solution += math.comb(total-P, length)
print(solution)
```

This code prints `8 388 480` which should be the number you are looking for.

---

**Explanation:**

For each length, we know that there should be at least one `P` element. So for each `P` possible, we count the number of sets containing it. This can be done using [math.comb](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-comb-method/) which is just n choose k.

---

**Performance:**

On my computer, here is the speed of the new algorithm for `S_num=16` and `S_num=7`:

```
106 µs ± 3.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Or just google [(2^16 - 1) * 2^7](https://www.google.com/search?q=(2%5E16+-+1)+*+2%5E7).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it by writing a function that returns the `count` and all of your *"special"* combinations.

```python
from itertools import chain, combinations

def card_shark(P, S):
    total_array = []
    P_num, S_num = len(P), len(S)
    for p in chain.from_iterable(combinations(P, r) for r in range(1, P_num + 1)):
        for s in chain.from_iterable(combinations(S, r) for r in range(0, S_num + 1)):
            total_array.append(list(p+s))
    return len(total_array), total_array
```

Here's an example using it.

```python
P_num = 16
S_num = 7

P = list(range(1,P_num+1))
S = list(range(1,S_num+1))
P = ["P" + str(suit) for suit in P]
S = ["S" + str(suit) for suit in S]

count, total_array = card_shark(P, S)

print(count)
# 8388480

print(total_array[:5])
# [['P1'], ['P1', 'S1'], ['P1', 'S2'], ['P1', 'S3'], ['P1', 'S4']]

print(total_array[-2:])
# [['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14', 'P15', 'P16', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7'], ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'P10', 'P11', 'P12', 'P13', 'P14', 'P15', 'P16', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7']]

%timeit count, total_array = card_shark(P, S)
# 2.6 s ± 33.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Or, to get `total_array` you could just *smush* it all together into a *one-liner* list comprehension and go slightly faster.

```python
%timeit total_array = [list(p+s) for p in chain.from_iterable(combinations(P, r) for r in range(1, P_num + 1)) for s in chain.from_iterable(combinations(S, r) for r in range(0, S_num + 1))]
# 2.33 s ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is that of the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). The power set of a set `A` is the set of all subsets of `A`, and is of size `2 ** len(A)` (since an element is either in or out). In your case, every subset of `S` is acceptable, but only the non-empty subsets of `P` are. Thus, you have

`(2 ** len(P) - 1) * (2 ** len(S))`

acceptable combinations. The following generator is an efficient way to generate only acceptable combinations:

```py
from itertools import combinations


def make_combinations(P, S):
    def power_set(iterable):
        s = list(iterable)

        for r in range(len(s) + 1):
            yield from combinations(s, r)

    for p in power_set(P):
        if p:
            for s in power_set(S):
                yield p + s
```

With some driver code:

```py
P = [f"P{num}" for num in range(1, 17)]  # = 16 total
S = [f"S{num}" for num in range(1, 8)]  # = 7 total

print((2 ** len(P) - 1) * (2 ** len(S)))

for combination in make_combinations(P, S):
    print(combination)  # or do something else
```

Which yields for the first ten combinations:

```
('P1',)
('P1', 'S1')
('P1', 'S2')
('P1', 'S3')
('P1', 'S4')
('P1', 'S5')
('P1', 'S6')
('P1', 'S7')
('P1', 'S1', 'S2')
('P1', 'S1', 'S3')
('P1', 'S1', 'S4')
```

Note that writing the combinations to the terminal inside the loop is particularly slow. You could look at for example Pingu's answer on how to improve that.